# Categorical semantics for dynamic epistemic logic

Tags: logic, category-theory, modal-logic

Dynamic epistemic logic tries to reason about knowledge that certain actors (people, machines, etc.) have and how it can change in response to outside events. It is usually possible to discuss such a logic with the help of Kripke semantics.

> Has anyone worked on *categorical* semantics for any kind of dynamic
>   epistemic logic (with multiple actors)?

I am aware, that "probably not" is very likely a possible answer, but I still want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes a year and a half late, but categorical semantics for DEL seem to be cutting edge research. Kohei Kishida lays out a categorical semantics for a flavour of DEL in this paper: [Categories for Dynamic Epistemic Logic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.08753.pdf)
. Alexandru Baltag also provides interesting algebraic semantics in this other paper: [Epistemic actions as resources](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608166.pdf). I think both papers may be appealing to you.